# Provisioned Appx not installing for new users

Tags: windows-10, deployment

I am trying to add some updated/extra packages to a Windows 10 Installer Image. (eg Updated Desktop App Installer and PowerShell)

I am able to provision the packages to the mounted WIM image without error, and the image can be used to successfully install windows.

I was under the impression that provisioned packages are installed for all new users, but the packages I've added are not.

I am able to manually install them (offline, nothing pulled from the internet) using powershell with the following:

```
$package = Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller" }
Add-AppxPackage -RegisterByFamilyName -MainPackage $package.PackageName
```

Am I missing a step somewhere when generating my install.wim that causes them not to automatically install or is this the expected result?

I can add a script to run at firstlogon to automatically install them like above, but I'd prefer not to if I don't have to.

**Update**

Below is an example of how I added the DesktopAppInstaller.

```
# example
# the following files exist
# C:\Deploy\install.wim
# C:\Deploy\Packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle
# C:\Deploy\Packages\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.7.appx
# C:\Deploy\Packages\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx
# C:\Deploy\Packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe_License1.xml
# C:\Deploy\mount (an empty folder)    

$packages = "C:\Deploy\Packages"
$mount = "C:\Deploy\mount"
$image = "C:\Deploy\install.wim"

Mount-WindowsImage -Path $mount -ImagePath $image -Index 1

Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Path $mount -PackagePath $packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle -DependencyPackagePath $packages\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.7.appx,$packages\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx -LicensePath $packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe_License1.xml

Dismount-WindowsImage -Path $mount -Save

# the updated install.wim is then copied to the installation media
```

**Update**

Reading some of the documentation, looks like it may not be possible. I downloaded them from GitHub but it's still probably considered a store app since you can get it from there.

> You cannot sideload an app that has been downloaded from the Microsoft Store. To install Windows apps that are not part of your business line, you must use the Microsoft Store.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sideload-apps-with-dism-s14?view=windows-11

**Update**

After further experimentation, the apps are eventually installed without any user interaction.

However the ~15 minutes it takes to do so is less than ideal!

Looking at the AppxLogs, there was a period of about 15 mins after a "Edge" or "Search" (WSearch Service) task started before the installation happens but I couldn't figure out what they were doing or how to stop them.

I couldn't find a way to execute the manual command above automatically as it needs administrator privileges, but after reading the docs, its only `Get-AppxProvisionedPackage` that requires this, `Add-AppxPackage` will run fine.

Below is an example of how I added a RunOnce task to speed up the install.

```
# working example
# the following files exist
# C:\Deploy\install.wim
# C:\Deploy\Packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle
# C:\Deploy\Packages\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.7.appx
# C:\Deploy\Packages\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx
# C:\Deploy\Packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe_License1.xml
# C:\Deploy\mount (an empty folder)    

$packages = "C:\Deploy\Packages"
$mount = "C:\Deploy\mount"
$image = "C:\Deploy\install.wim"

Mount-WindowsImage -Path $mount -ImagePath $image -Index 1

Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Path $mount -PackagePath $packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle -DependencyPackagePath $packages\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.7.appx,$packages\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx -LicensePath $packages\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe_License1.xml

$packageName = Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Path $mount | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PackageName

reg load "HKU\DefaultUser" "$mount\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT"

$key = "Registry::HKU\DefaultUser\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"

# create RunOnce if not exist 
# close the handle to allow the hive to unload successfully
if ( -Not (Test-Path $key)) {
    (New-Item -Path $key -Force).Handle.Close()
}

New-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name "DeployAppInstaller" -PropertyType ExpandString -Value ("""%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"" -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command ""Add-AppxPackage -RegisterByFamilyName -MainPackage '{0}'""" -f $packageName) -Force

# sleep may not be required
[gq]::Collect()
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

reg unload "HKU\DefaultUser"

Dismount-WindowsImage -Path $mount -Save

# the updated install.wim is then copied to the installation media
```